# How to test hitting an internal Network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I have a requirement to use an internal NLB to communicate with other resources inside a VPC. I am able to create an NLB and an AWS Lambda function inside the VPC but for some reason my requests from Lambda hang and time out. I have tried putting the NLB and Lambda function inside separate subnets, in the same subnets, in separate SGs, in the same SGs, but nothing works. I'm not sure how you're supposed to hit internal NLBs to test them. Here is what I have spun up with CloudFormation:

```
  NLB:                               # The Network Load Balancer
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer"
    Properties:
      Scheme: "internal"
      Subnets: !Ref NlbSubnetIds     # I'm providing 3 subnets out of the 6 available
      Type: "network"
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        - Key: access_logs.s3.enabled
          Value: true
        - Key: access_logs.s3.bucket 
          Value: !Ref AccessLogBucketNlb
        - Key: load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled
          Value: true
  NlbTargetGroup:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup"
    Properties:
        HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
        HealthCheckProtocol: "TCP"
        HealthyThresholdCount: 3
        Matcher: !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
        Port: 80
        Protocol: "TCP"
        TargetType: "ip"
        UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
        VpcId: !Ref VpcId

  NlbListener:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref NlbTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref NLB
      Port: '80'
      Protocol: TCP
```

From my Lambda function in the same VPC:

```
import json
import urllib3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'http://<NLB DNS Name>.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
                     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    print(r.read())
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

All of the Inbound / Outbound rules in the ACLs allow for communication as well as the Security Groups so I'm certain it's not that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you specified proper execution permissions for the lambda?

Comment: What do you have _behind_ the NLB? That is, to what resource should the NLB pass the request? An NLB doesn't have Security Groups, so the security group on the receiving resource will be used. Check that it is accepting inputs from the Lambda ENI.

Comment: Behind the NLB I have tried 2 different things, 1) an ALB sitting on top of an ECS cluster and 2) another Lambda function. In the ELB monitoring I'm not seeing any requests hitting the NLB to begin with though.

Comment: did you figure this out, i am facing the same ussue

Comment: @opensource-developer I don't think I ever solved it, sorry

Comment: We need to see the CloudFormation for the resources behind your NLB otherwise this is not reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try using the VPC network analyzer to see connectivity between resources within your VPC

Blog
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-insights-analyzes-reachability-and-visibility-in-vpcs/

Docs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/network-access-analyzer/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **EC2 instance** within same VPC and try to hit the NLB using that EC2 instance. We are using the same approach to test our endpoints

Comment: I need to know for making requests from a Lambda function. It's more of a networking/permissions issue than infrastructure. I'm curious though if that is the blocker? i.e. it's not possible from Lambda but it is possible from EC2. Why would that be the case?

Comment: You can do trace route/ nslookup to know the root cause of issue from ec2 easily. Most likely this is a security group issue.